# datasets and joins. ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, dataset

I have 3 tables. Namely Job_Master,Print_details,Paper_Details.

The Structure of the table is as follows:

**Job_Master:**

jobno   jobname amount

1   A   100
2   B   200
3   C   300

**Print_Details** id being the PK and jobno being FK

id  jobno   color

1   1   Cyan
2   1   Red
3   2   Black
4   3   Black
5   3   Green

**Paper Details** id being the PK and jobno being FK

id  jobno   Type

1   1   Art Paper
2   1   Photo Paper
3   2   Art Paper
4   3   Copier
5   3   Glossy Paper

I want a write a query in SQL server or perform Dataset operations in ASP.net so as to display the below resultset in the grid view:

**Desired Resultset:**

```
jobno jobname printDetails                    paperDetails                  amount

1     A       CYAN,RED                        Art Paper,Photo Paper         100
2     B       Black                           Art Paper                     200
3     C       Black,Green                     Copier,Glossy Paper           300
```

is this possible using dataset operations in ASP.net or in a SQL server query. I am using SQL server 2008 R2 as my database and the fromt end has been designed using ASP.net3.5.

Any help on this is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have stored the result of the below query in the data set SELECT   a.Jobno, a.jobname, b.color,c.type
 FROM job_master a
 left JOIN cprint_details b
 ON a.jobno=b.jobno 
 left join paper_details c on a.jobno=c.jobno
 ORDER BY a.jobno but it does not give me a the desired result. how to combine the color and type columns in resultset based on the jobno to get a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Jobno, a.jobname,  COALESCE(b.color + ', ', '') + b.color,COALESCE(c.type + ', ', '') + c.type
FROM job_master a left JOIN cprint_details b ON a.jobno=b.jobno 
left join paper_details c on a.jobno=c.jobno 
ORDER BY a.jobno
```

Read here for more info  [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: Thanks Prince. The query does work and combines the result of two rows in a single column but outputs the same results two time.

Comment: `1     A       CYAN,RED                        Art Paper,Photo Paper         100 <br>1     A       CYAN,RED                        Art Paper,Photo Paper         100 `

Comment: it still giving two rows for each jobno with multiple entries in print and paper table